# When copy+pasting an object from Blender add-on "Vegetation", materials vary for each iteration

Tags: materials, add-on

Blender 3.0.1 but it's done this with all versions.

After adding a particular plant from the Vegetation add-on, I copy and paste plants, sourcing from the initial plant. I'm getting some variation in material appearances between the copies and haven't been able to track down the source of this problem.[image: Shader Editor view] [image: See color differences between the round shrubs and between the two columnar conifers]

Comment: Blender doesn't have a built-in 'vegetation' addon, so you'll have to ask the addon's author since it's a third-party addon.

Comment: At first glance I'd try sliding the field name "Random Sa..." all the way to the left (0)